# Searching for a case-sensitive VBA version of sumproduct function

Tags: vba, excel

What I am looking for is a suggestion regarding which formula to use for a macro. This macro is meant to search a column for a string ( "CAN" ), and then return the summation of all of the corresponding numeric values from a column 3 rows over, so long as the case sensitive string is present.

I've searched for the VBA version of vlookup, tried sumproduct, index/match, etc., but the necessity of this macro being not only case sensitive but also a summation of multiple numeric values has led to roadblocks with all of these functions.

I am not an experienced programmer by any means, and I am sorry if this post is too vague. To make this simpler (hopefully), what I'm looking for is the best function to use if I want to make a macro that could take the following list, search for "Apples", and have the value 21 return.

If this is not what this site is for... Just let me know and I'll delete this post.

```
Oranges Apples  $10 

apples Oranges  $12 

Pears Grapes    $14 

Grapes Oranges  $18 

APPLES Oranges  $19 

Oranges Pears   $16 

Apples Oranges  $11
```

Comment: Does this need to be done in VBA? You mentioned VLOOKUP, but this seems like a problem for pivot tables. Also, could you clarify, your example makes it seems as though you are searching both the first and second columns for the text. Is this correct?

Comment: Why VBA?  This can be done with worksheet formulas.  FIND is case sensitive, and  could be incorporated into your SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: I would like for this to be done in VBA, as my boss wants this go be a macro that he can re-use in his spreadsheet over and over again, as monthly orders / shipments come in. However, I had no considered using find and sumproduct together... I will work on trying to figure this out.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the function is meant to search the first column... and if the string is found, (case sensitive), then the second column should be added to the summation.

Comment: In VBA, I would use Range.Find method for the range to search, and just Offset to the range to sum.  Look at VBA Help for Range.Find, and an example as to how to do multiple Finds.

Comment: If the goal is re-usability, you really want to check out [pivot tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html). They do this exact thing natively in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reiterate here: Look into [Pivot Tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html). They're a little intimidating at first, but they are designed to track this kind of data. That link gives a tutorial.

If you are adamant that this is to be done in VBA, this should be pretty easy, as VBA string compare is case sensitive.

Basically, you want to loop through each cell in a columns
(you can use a for loop with rows.count for this, or a while loop like I did below). Then compare the value of each cell to "CAN". If it's equal, total = total + cell.offset(0,2).value.

**EDIT**

[image: Excel workbook]

```
Sub countApple()
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim col as Integer
    total = 0
    i = 1
    col = 1 'This will search A. 2 would search B, and so on
    While Not Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, col).Value = "" 
           If Cells(i, col).Value = "Apple" Then
                total = total + Cells(i, col).Offset(0, 2).Value
           End If
           i = i + 1
    Wend
    MsgBox (total) 'Displays 8
End Sub
```

This code will work (provided there are no empty rows in A). If there is anything you don't understand about it, don't hesitate to contact me :)

Comment: Ok, I am a bit new to VBA, but hopefully this advice will help me figure this out. I'll look around for what this looks like in particular on the internet tonight. If you have any examples, that would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for being so behind the curve... New to this, and also to the job.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I think this is exactly what I needed, and on my work computer tomorrow I'll check once and for all. The only thing I could see going wrong is the fact that the string I am searching for is "CAN", and the column values will be something like CAN - Amazon.. so I am looking for a string within a string. I bet I can alter the if statement in such a way that this is dealt with properly. I'll know for sure in the morning. Is there any way I can upvote you or give you reputation points or something?

Comment: You can use the [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264811(v=office.14).aspx) function. For example, `Dim pos As Integer pos = InStr("find CAN in this string", "CAN")`. If it returns 0, it was not found. And if this answer helped you, you can click the checkmark on the left next to it :)